# Specify Compile Order in Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have my React components broken up into separate JS files for manageability and using the following command to compile the files in my src folder into a single JavaScript file:

```
babel -w src -o scripts.js
```

My problem is the order in which the files are compiling. I want to make certain that the base file containing my render() function is last and that a file containing 'use strict;' is first.

Is there a way to tell Babel the order of files to process?

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: Have you considered using webpack?

Comment: I haven't, @azium. I'm still a bit new to the React world, so right now I'm just using straight-up Babel to compile it. I have read some articles that mention webpack. Is that the best solution?

Comment: using create-react-app is definitely the best solution https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much, @azium!